# tabular margin left overflow

Tags: tables

I try to build a tabular with latex and experience a little overflow of the horizontal line on my tabular on the left. whatever I tried everything just switched the overflow so it sometimes happens on the right side and with other configurations, like shown, on the left.
It's just about 1 mm but that shouldn't be...

Heres the code that procudes it:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l||p{10cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Risikobeschreibung} & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Auswirkungen}   & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Warnzeichen}    & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Eintrittswahrscheinlichkeit}    & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Vermeidungsstrategie}   & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Maßnahmen bei Eintreten} & xyz\\
        \hline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Risikoanalyse}
        \label{tab:Risikoanalyse}

\end{table}
```

[image: Overflow of margin on left side just about 1mm long very tiny]

Hope you can see it on the image.

Comment: I can't replicate this on MikTeX 2.9 neither XeLaTeX nor PDFLaTeX. Can you complete your example to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem ?

Comment: As @percuße said you need to provide a full example, however you might try `\usepackage{array}` as that changes the rule positioning logic as well as its other table extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a displaying error of adobe reader.

After printing the overflow is not visible but on adobe reader it is.

So for me it's nothing to care if I print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `tabular*` instead of `tabular`. Then you can set the width of your table to `textwidth` (width of the text).

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|l||p{10cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Risikobeschreibung} & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Auswirkungen}   & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Warnzeichen}    & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Eintrittswahrscheinlichkeit}    & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Vermeidungsstrategie}   & xyz\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Maßnahmen bei Eintreten} & xyz\\
        \hline\hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \caption{Risikoanalyse}
        \label{tab:Risikoanalyse}

\end{table}
```